# Retrieve contents of URL as string

Tags: ruby, open-uri

For tedious reasons to do with Hpricot, I need to write a function that is passed a URL, and returns the whole contents of the page as a single string.

I'm close. I know I need to use OpenURI, and it should look something like this:

```
require 'open-uri'
open(url) {
  # do something mysterious here to get page_string
}
puts page_string
```

Can anyone suggest what I need to add?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `open` method passes an `IO` representation of the resource to your block when it yields. You can read from it using the [`IO#read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002245) method

```
open([mode [, perm]] [, options]) [{|io| ... }] 
open(path) { |io| data = io.read }
```

Comment: thanks! and thanks for explaining what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @saihgala [URI.join](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-join)

Answer (score 66):

You can do the same without OpenURI:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def open(url)
  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
end

page_content = open('http://www.google.com')
puts page_content
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.google.com'))
```

Comment: What's the disadvantage of using open-uri?

Comment: Yeah, it's super confusing that this more-complicated answer has way more upvotes than the other ones. I tried searching for a reason myself and found [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16764302/199712) that seems to recommend OpenURI over Net::HTTP in most cases, which just makes things more confusing. THANKS, OBAMA

Comment: open-uri internally patches `Kernel.open`.  Here is an [article](http://sakurity.com/blog/2015/02/28/openuri.html) talking about things one should be aware of when using open-uri.  I have also come across method naming conflicts `open` when using it together with other libraries such as bunny gem (which also implements `open`)

Comment: complicated? This is super simple (you can also do it on one line `Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.google.com'))`. And it doesn't do crazy things under the hood.

Answer (score 12):

```
require 'open-uri'
open(url) do |f|
  page_string = f.read
end
```

See also the documentation of [IO class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html)

Answer (score 5):

I was also very confused what to use for better performance and speedy results. I ran a benchmark for both to make it more clear:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'net/http'
require "uri"
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.google.com"
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("net-http:")   { content = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body if url }
  x.report("open-uri:")   { open(url){|f| content =  f.read } if url }
end
```

Its result is:

```
              user     system      total        real
net-http:  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.097779)
open-uri:  0.030000   0.010000   0.040000 (  0.864526)
```

I'd like to say that it depends on what your requirement is and how you want to process.

Comment: I tried a similar benchmark, and have found both methods to be about equal in speed, although it's hard to tell because external factors affect download speed (eg. wifi, other apps)

Answer (score 4):

To make code a little clearer, the OpenURI `open` method will return the value returned by the block, so you can assign `open`'s return value to your variable.  For example:

```
xml_text = open(url) { |io| io.read }
```

Comment: nice, here's a one liner to get amazon EC2 public IP ranges: `ruby -r json -ropen-uri -e 'JSON.parse(open("https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json") { |io| io.read })["prefixes"].each {|p| puts #{p["ip_prefix"] if p["service"]=="EC2"}; '`

Comment: fixed typo in the one-liner: `ruby -r json -r open-uri -e 'JSON.parse(open("https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json") { |io| io.read })["prefixes"].each {|p| puts p["ip_prefix"] if p["service"]=="EC2"}; '`

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Ruby 3.0, calling `URI.open` via `Kernel#open` [has been removed](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/NEWS_md.html#label-Compatibility+issues), so instead call `URI.open` directly:

```rb
require 'open-uri'
page_string = URI.open(url, &:read)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead:

```
require 'open-uri' 
content = URI(your_url).read
```

Comment: Not sure why this is currently downvoted – on Ruby 3.1 this is the shortest/subjectively nicest way of doing it.

Answer (score -2):

```
require 'open-uri'
open(url) {|f|  #url must specify the protocol
str = f.read()
}
```

Comment: How does this differ from the solution mentioned previously by Teoulas?