# What is the difference between Ruby's 'open-uri' and 'Net:HTTP' gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, net-http, open-uri

It seems like both of these gems perform very similar tasks.  Can anyone give examples of where one gem would be more useful than the other?  I don't have specific code that I'm referring to, I'm more wondering about general use cases for each gem.  I know this is a short question, I will fill in the blanks upon request.  Thanks.

Comment: If `open-uri` fits its name, it probably means it can handle other schemes than `http`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason they look like they perform similar tasks is OpenURI is a wrapper for Net::HTTP, Net::HTTPS, and Net::FTP.

Usually, unless you feel you need a lower level interface, using OpenURI is better as you can get by with less code. Using OpenURI you can open a URL/URI and treat it as a file.

See: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html
and http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3//libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net.html

Comment: Thanks Alex.  Sorry, what's a 'wrapper'?

Comment: A wrapper is simply a library that uses one or more other libraries to create a nicer, higher level interface. In this specific case, OpenURI uses the Net libraries to expose a more familiar interface, i.e. that of reading from a file.

Answer (score 7):

I just found out that `open` does follow redirections, while `Net::HTTP` doesn't, which is an important difference.

For example, `open('http://www.stackoverflow.com') { |content| puts content.read }` will display the proper HTML after following the redirection, while `Net::HTTP.get(URI('http://www.stackoverflow.com'))` will show the redirection message and 302 status code.