# Ruby: what is the difference between using open() and NET::HTTP module to fetch web content?

Tags: ruby, http

A separate SO post offers different methods for fetching web content in Ruby, but doesn't fully explain why one is preferable to the other.

What is the difference between using open() and the NET::HTTP module, as demonstrated below, to fetch web content? Why is NET::HTTP considered the "better" approach?

```
**open() 1:**    
require 'open-uri'
file = open('http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=zezima')
contents = file.read

**open() 2:**
require 'open-uri'
source = open('http://www.google.com', &:read)

**NET::HTTP 1:**
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
url = "http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player=zezima"
r = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url).host, URI.parse(url).path)
```

Comment: OpenURI is an easy-to-use wrapper for net/http, net/https and net/ftp from the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html

Comment: Is this of any use?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764030/what-is-the-difference-between-rubys-open-uri-and-nethttp-gems

Comment: Where is 'NET::HTTP considered the "better" approach'??

Comment: comments on the accepted answer indicate that it's better in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854207/getting-webpage-content-with-ruby-im-having-troubles. is it not? we don't know; hence the question.

Comment: the other SO questions don't explain the differences among the three choices and when one might be preferable over another...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule of thumb: **Use [`OpenURI`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) whenever you can.**

The reason is that [`OpenURI`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) is just a wrapper around [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), therefore it will require *less code* to be written. So if all you do is performing simple GET requests, go for it.

On the other hand, prefer [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) if you want some lower-level functionality that you `OpenURI` does not give you. It is not a *better* approach, but it provides more *flexibility* in terms of configuration.

As the [official documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) states:

> *If you are only performing a few GET requests you should try OpenURI.*