# How to convert following php code to ruby code

Tags: php, ruby

Following code downloads json file from url. I want to convert it to ruby code

```
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(array(
        "http" => array(
            "method" => "GET",
            "header" => "Authorization: ". $authorizationHeader ."\r\n".
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode\r\n"
        )
```

not able to find suitable way to do it in ruby. Any help on this please....

Comment: By learning ruby so simple !!! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193538/ruby-retrieve-contents-of-url-as-string